# SQL: How to add columns for rows given an array of variable length row names

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

Say I have a database of items, and each item has the following columns: name, amount1, amount2, amount3. Given an array of names (that varies in length), how can I query the database to get the sum of each column for each column for the specified names? So if I have an array of "thing1" and "thing2", it will return the sum of amount1 from thing1 and thing2, and the same for amount2 and amount 3.

For example:
example db :

[image: db pic]

names = [thing1, thing2]

query = ?

output :

[image: something like this pic]

I have used the following query but cannot figure out how to extend it to handle a variable length array of names, nor all the columns:

```
SELECT SUM(amount1) AS Amount1Sum FROM table where name = "thing1" or name ="thing2";
```

For some additional context, this request is made from a node.js server using express.

Here is the route where it is implemented in my server (using one of the suggestions from below):

```
    app.post("/counter",function(req, res) {
        let items = req.body.name
        let sqlquery = "SELECT SUM(amount1) as amount1Sum, SUM(amount2) as amount2Sum, SUM(amount3) as amount3Sum FROM table where name in (?)";

        // query database
        db.query(sqlquery, items, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err.message);
            }
            console.log(result)
        });
    });
```

Output for checking the form with thing1 and thing2 is `[ RowDataPacket { amount1Sum: 213, amount2Sum: 5432, amount3Sum: 23} ]` and I confirmed that the array of names does include both thing1 and thing2. It's just returning thing1 columns, not adding the columns for all the names.

Comment: Could there be an amount4 ?

Comment: There could be. Barmar has answered the question below.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think Barmar has chosen to ignore what appears to be a fundamental flaw in your schema design. Is that helpful; well, I don't think so. :-(

Comment: I just realized I misinterpreted your question. There will not be an amount4, nor will the amount columns to be counted vary from what I specified. 

Originally I misread your question as asking if the names array might include thing3 or thing4, etc. Which is totally not what you said, so my apologies on the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE name IN (?)` and pass the JS array as the corresponding parameter to match a dynamic list.

```
names = ['thing1', 'thing2'];
connection.query(`SELECT SUM(amount1) AS amount1sum, SUM(amount2) AS amount2sum, SUM(amount3) AS amount3sum
FROM table
WHERE name IN (?)`, [names], function(err, results) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not actually sum the columns. Instead it just gives me the values from the first name included in the array. It doesn't seem to iterate over the array like I expected. I updated my post to show this implementation.

Comment: I think you need to nest the array to make `?` expand into the whole list. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

just sum all columns:

```
SELECT SUM(amount1) as Amount1Sum, SUM(amount2) as Amount2Sum, SUM(amount3) as Amount3Sum 
FROM table where name in ('thing1', 'thing2');
```

Comment: This get's me close but I am still trying to figure out how to pass the array of names to this query. I will update the post with the implementation. I am substituting "thing1," and "thing2" with ? and then passing the array as an argument into the query (which should replace the '?') but it's only returning the value for thing1 instead of adding them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, Sum(amoun1), Sum(amoun3), Sum(amoun3),
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Not quite - I only want to add the columns for a given set of names. Your query adds the columns for all names, not just the supplied ones (thing1 and thing2 in my example).

Comment: This was very helpful and helped me get to the final solution in combination with Barmar's answer here as well. Thank you for the help.